# simulation error in proteus

Tags: proteus

I'm trying to simulate the attached circuit in Proteus but i got the following errors after i made the branch attached to 32v tap of  the transformer.

[SPICE] transient GMIN stepping at time=0.00461295

[SPICE] transient GMIN stepping at time=0.00461295

[SPICE] TRAN:  Timestep too small; timestep = 1.25e-019: trouble with instance D3.

[image]

Comment: why is the added portion on the bottom half so horribly drawn? ... it should look something like the top half of the schematic

Comment: sorry, i just was putting some ideas in rush and when it works i make it in better arrange

Comment: It looks like you have a floating pin in the secondary of your tansformer, but also that you have no ground reference in the primary. Try adding some `1g` resistors from the floating pin and from one side of the primary (whichever) to the ground. Also try adding some loads in there.